Problem calculating a common measure or summing measures row by row in Power BI
There are several tables - one table with facts, the rest are reference books. They are all correctly linked to each other by a "star" link.
Connected from Power BI Desktop to Analysis Services to a tabular model. The links are already configured there and the calculation is done.
It is necessary to calculate the indicator A using the formula A = B-C, where B and C are measures.
A = Sum of the actual indicator (B) – Sum of the planned indicator (C), where
Sum of the actual indicator (B) = I sum the data by the column in the fact table sum(...)
Sum of the planned indicator (C) (calculated using a complex formula) = Average daily sales * 50 * (Planned inventory in months), where
Average daily sales = 0.8 * Sales for the last 30 days / % of days in stock (last 30 days) + 0.9 * Sales for the average 30 days / % of days in stock (average 30 days) + 0.4 * Sales for the first 30 days / % of days in stock (first 30 days)
I calculate the sales for the last 30 days, % of days in stock and Average daily sales using measures.
Planned inventory = (12 / Planned turnover). I find it by calculating the division measure 12 / average (Planned turnover)
As a result, I create a table by goods, where I include all the listed indicators including A, B, C. By goods (line by line), indicator A is calculated correctly, but the total A for all goods is calculated incorrectly (for example, "Sales for the last 30 days" we calculate the sum for goods 1, 2, 3), since when calculating indicator C, each composite measure is calculated within itself for all goods at once, which is why the total for all goods A is incorrect. Tell me how this can be fixed? I would also be satisfied with the option - how to add up indicators A for all goods line by line, if this can somehow be bypassed. You cannot create columns when connecting to a tabular model - only measures.
